# How does a shell (bash, for example) expand wildcard patterns?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

Assume that a directory has 100 files starting with the letter 'a'.

If I do a `grep <some string> a*` from the terminal, how will the shell handle this?

Will it expand the regular expression, get a list of all files starting with a and grep on each one of those sequentially? Or is there some other way?

Assume that I have an array of the above filenames that begin with 'a'. Will it take more/less time if I write a for loop and do the iteration myself in a shell script or a c program?

Comment: BTW, it's a `glob` not a regular expression. Big difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, a nitpick: a string like `a*` in normal shell syntax is a glob, which works differently from regular expressions.

On a high-level overview, the shell interpreter (i.e. bash) expands the string `a*` to a list of every file name matching the pattern `a*`.  These then become part of the command line parameters to a *single* instance of `grep` (for the programmers, all the expanded words go as separate strings into the `argv` argument of `main`).  That single `grep` command then parses the arguments in whatever way it chooses, and it is up to `grep` to interpret those arguments as file names, options, option arguments, regular expressions, etc., and take the appropriate actions.  Everything occurs sequentially (AFAIK no `grep` implementation uses multiple threads).

If you implement a loop in a shell script to do that same thing, it is almost guaranteed to be slower than the above process, for the following reasons.  If you spawn a new grep process for each file, it will most certainly be slower due to the overhead of process creation being multiplied unnecessarily.  If you constructed the argument list yourself in the shell script and used a single instance of `grep`, anything you do in shell will still be slower because shell commands have to interpreted (by bash), which adds an extra layer of code, and you'll just be re-implementing what bash was already doing faster internally in compiled code.

As for writing it yourself in C, you can probably easily get comparable performance to the process described in the first paragraph but it's unlikely that you'll be able to achieve enough of a performance gain over the current grep/bash implementations to justify the time spent without delving into machine-specific performance optimizations or sacrificing portability.  Maybe you could try to come up with an arbitrarily parallelizable version of `grep`, but even that may not help as you are more likely to be I/O bound than CPU bound.  Glob expansion and grep are already "fast enough" for most "normal" purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. Actually, I need to grep gzipped files (few GB each). I have a list of those files. I now have a choice of either building a regex (complicated) to match those files or iterate over the known list and run grep on each one of those (easy). Hence the worry about performance.

Comment: try `zcat` and `zgrep`; no need to decompress them one by one

Comment: Yes, of course. I am using zgrep.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it will expand to a list of files and feeds the resulting list to the `grep` program. At least that is what `man bash` says in subsection *Pathname Expansion*.

There is another way of using the expansion in simple cases as you mention: write `grep <some_string> a` and **before pressing `*`**, press <kbd>ESC</kbd>. This will expand the list of matched files right in the command line, so you can verify the list is OK before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

As for the second part of your question, it depends. If you mean to write a for-loop that runs grep on each of the files in turn, then it would definitely be slower, because the grep program will be run not once, but once per file. However, what **is** important to keep in mind is that there is a certain *limit* on the expanded length of command-line arguments you can use, though it is typically quite high. To see that, you can try `grep adasdsadf /usr/*/*/* >/dev/null`.

Comment: `ESC+*` is not exactly the same as letting bash expand * because `ESC+*` will insert dotfiles (names that start with a `.`) whereas the expansion of `*` depends on the `dotglob` `shopt` setting.  The key sequence to expand and insert globs is `C-x *` by default and maps to the readline command `glob-expand-word`.

Comment: @jw013 Thanks for the information! It doesn't seem to change the case of `a*` expansion, but is certainly important in broader scope.

Comment: `zsh` note: just hitting the *tab* key on expandable parameters (glob patterns, brace-expansion, command-substitution, …) will expand them.

Comment: @jw013 Actually, I just tested the `C-x` shortcut and it does **not** expand the list of files on my system (using bash).

Comment: @roz It is in the man page (search `glob-expand-word`).  Are you sure you were using it correctly?  You need a valid glob expression already typed on the command line right before your cursor because it won't expand anything out of "thin air", if you will.

Comment: @jw0 Aah, so I need to type, for example, `*` then `Ctrl+x` then `*` to have all the files listed. OK, that works. But it's much longer to type than `Esc`+`*` :)

Comment: @roz Right - I hardly ever use it anyways, just wanted to point out the (rather nitpicky) difference :).  `C-x *` only does globs which only do filenames, but `Esc *` actually does a lot more since it is `insert-completions`, as in all possible completions.  This means using `Esc *` on an empty command line will insert the name of every single executable file in your `$PATH`, for instance.